# Finding a polygon with maximum edges

Tags: java, algorithm

Essentially my problem is this: given a number n that signifies the width and height of a square grid, I need to find the points of a convex, 90 degree rotationally symmetric polygon with a maximum number of sides that fits within the grid, where points are only able to be made on the grid's lattice points and sides must go straight from one point to another. My attempt at it resulted in a total of 2516 sides for n = 100000, however I've been led to believe that it should have 7592. The function I used is below, and the problem description itself is [here](http://acm.uva.es/p/v110/11006.html).

```
static Point[] getPoints(final int n) {
    // first, figure out the max number of sides
        int sides = 0; boolean jump = false;
        for(int inc = 2, max = 0; max < n; jump = !jump, sides += 4)
            max += (jump) ? ++inc : inc;
    // next, compute the point translations
        Point[] pts = new Point[sides];
        Point[] translations = new Point[sides];
        translations[0] = new Point(0,1); jump = true;
        // systematically generate translations used
        for(int i = 1, j = 1; i < sides/4; i++, jump = !jump)
            translations[i] = (jump) ? new Point(1, j++) : new Point(j, 1);
        // sort the first 4th into correct translation order
        Arrays.sort(translations, new Comparator<Point>() {
            public int compare(Point a, Point b) {
                if(a == null || b == null) return 0;
                return a.x < b.x ? -1 : a.x == b.x ? 
                a.y > b.y ? -1 : a.y == b.y ? 0 : 1 : 1;
            }
        });
        // use first 4th to generate the rest
        for(int i = translations.length/4; i < translations.length; i++)
            translations[i] = new Point(translations[i-(translations.length/4)].y,
                    -translations[i-(translations.length/4)].x);
    // finally, find first point and use translations to generate the rest
        int y = 0; jump = true;
        for(int i = 0, j = 1; i < sides; i += 4, jump = !jump)
            y += (jump) ? j++ : 1;
        pts[0] = new Point(0, y);
        for(int i = 1; i < pts.length; i++) {
            pts[i] = new Point(pts[i-1]);
            pts[i].translate(translations[i].x, translations[i].y);
        }
    // now reverse x's and y's
        for(int i = 0; i < pts.length; i++)
            pts[i] = new Point(pts[i].y, pts[i].x);
    // and then put last point in front
        Point first = pts[pts.length-1];
        for(int i = pts.length-1; i > 0; i--)
            pts[i] = pts[i-1];
        pts[0] = first;
    // and then adjust points to make the wheel symmetrical around the n-block
        int w = 0, h = 0;
        for(int i = 1; i < sides/4; i++) {
            h += translations[i].x;
            w += translations[i].y;
        }
        int adj = n - (w+h+1);
        for(int i = 1; i <= sides/4; i++) pts[i].translate(adj, 0);
        for(int i = (sides/4)+1; i <= sides/2; i++) pts[i].translate(adj, adj);
        for(int i = (sides/2)+1; i <= 3*(sides/4); i++) pts[i].translate(0, adj);
        return pts;
    }
```

Comment: what do you think should be output for n=4?

Comment: Link to the question does not exist.